# Can I separate all data by ";" using XPath?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, beautifulsoup, webdriver

I can't print out //*[@class="footballmaincontent"] from the specific website by xpath, thanks!

```
# -*- coding:UTF-8 -*-

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("url")

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source.encode('utf-8'),'html.parser')
lines = soup.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="footballmaincontent"]/tr')
print lines

driver.close()
display.stop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to get required output:

```
lines = ['; '.join([j.text for j in i.find_elements_by_xpath('./td/div | ./td/span/span | ./td/span[not(span)]') if j.text]) for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="footballmaincontent"]//tr[position()>2]') if i.text]

for line in lines:
    print line
```

Comment: thanks dears, but it seem not work at all ! in python 2.7, but anyway thanks a lot !

Comment: There was a typo. Try now

Comment: Dears, it seem cannot separate for the 1) THU ; 1 ; 2)Russia ; vs ; Saudi Arabia ; 3) Expected In Play start selling time: ; 14/06; 23:00 ; any method to do that, thanks !

Comment: Currently I get `'THU 1; RussiavsSaudi Arabia; Expected In Play start selling time:\n14/06 23:00; 1.31; 4.00; 10.00'`. What output do you expect to get? Do you mean you want to split `RussiavsSaudi Arabia ` into `Russia ; vs ; Saudi Arabia ` ?

Comment: Dears, thanks so much ! even FRI with 3 and 23/06 with 02:00 that two parts is still no separated, but let me trying by myself, thanks again <33